# Redirect based on Browser SNI support

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https, sni

I've implemented SSL on my site using SNI. Now I know that old browsers does not support SNI facility. What I'm asking is is it possible to redirect the user to some other landing page when he/she is trying to visit my site with a non SNI supported browser.

Please suggest me how can I implement it? I'm not able to find much heloful info about SNI based redirection. If there is some code snippet which you guys use to achive this, then please share it with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: yes, it is possible in theory, but probably not in any use case relevant in practice.

In detail:
HTTP redirection within a HTTPS connection is done *after* the TLS connection got established. That means, that you would first need to have a valid certificate which matches all the hosts you have on your site in order to establish the TLS connection. This is usually not the case if you are using SNI because if you have such certificate you would not need SNI at all.

Comment: So, you are saying that there is no way to do that? I have a valid certificate installed but I installed it over SNI. So is there no way to redirect a user if his browser does not support SNI?

Comment: To repeat myself: the **TLS handshake must be done before the redirect** can happen. This means you need to have a valid certificate suitable for non-SNI browsers and matching all hosts you want to redirect from. If you have this you can redirect, but then your would probably not need to use SNI at all. Which means, that there is probably no way for you to get what you want.